# Accessing AppData folder of all windows users C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, path

I need to get the path of each windows user AppData folder.
I tried to use

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

and it gives the path of the current user only.

I need to iterate all windows users and get the AppData path.

I looked for a solution in the web and tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091606/accessing-application-data-folder-path-for-all-windows-users) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867485/c-sharp-getting-the-path-of-appdata) but did not succeed.

I thought to go over all windows users as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247798/get-list-of-local-computer-usernames-in-windows) and somehow using the result of the current user AppData path combine to all users path, but I am not quit sure how to implement it.

Comment: What do you plan to _do_ with the path?  Unless your app is running as a highly-privileged user you are going to have issues _accessing_ those paths.

Also of those things you say you have tried, what for example goes wrong with this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/a/23093062/2701753

Comment: To get to the special folders of another user, you're going to need to look in that user's registry hive. This will require getting the list of user profiles (WMI's `Win32_UserProfile` should do that), loading the user's registry hive, and then looking in the right key.

Comment: Provide the code what you have tried and actual,expected result? It's helpful for us to figure it out.

Comment: @tolanj for some reason I missed the solution you mentioned. It worked. thanks a lot!